# How can I measure the build time for each component of a scons build?

Tags: scons, timing

I have a big C++ project that is built using scons. 
Its building slow and I want to make some changes to try to make it build faster.
Now I'd like to focus my time speeding up the parts of the build that are slowest.

How can I work out which files are taking the longest to compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding some extra stuff to the start of the CXXCOM variable. Scons uses this variable to do the actual compilation:

```
if os.getenv('BUILD_STYLE')=='timing':
  cxxcom = env['CXXCOM']
  env.Replace( CXXCOM = 'time '+cxxcom )
```

I then run scons using something like this

```
BUILD_STYLE=timing scons > timing_log.txt
```

and finally tidy up the log using some vim macros.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old, and has already been accepted, but it was recently referenced from another question. I think a much more elegant solution would be to use the SCons `--debug=time` command line option, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15044929/1158895).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using LInux, you could wrapper `gcc` or `g++` so that invocations of of the compiler use the `gtime` utility.  Every call to the compiler would look like:

```
/usr/bin/time /usr/bin/g++ [rest of command]
```

[BASH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) has some magical syntax that helps you avoid having to re-escape your arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash -f
PATH_TO_COMPILER_DIR=/usr/bin
/usr/bin/time $PATH_TO_COMPILER_DIR/"$@"
```

Then point your $PATH variable to have your compiler wrapper.

Then run SCons with only 1 parallel thread via option `-j1`.

Comment: +1, Doesn't quite solve the issue in the way I'd like, but it gave me some ideas that I used in my solution.