# calculate build elapsed time in SCons

Tags: time, scons

I have a project that consists of a binary and a set of static libraries it depends on. I'm trying to get the elapsed time for building each library without success.

I have tried to use `AddPreAction()/AddPostAction()` for calculating the elapsed time but `AddPreAction()` is called once all the source files the library depends on have been compiled (which makes sense).

There is a post related to this issue:

[How can I measure the build time for each component of a scons build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402262/how-can-i-measure-the-build-time-for-each-component-of-a-scons-build)

But I would prefer to look for a more elegant solution rather than overriding some environment variables and then have to parse the output in order to calculate the times.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can get timing information on various different aspects of the build using the `--debug=time` SCons command line option, as documented in the [SCons man pages](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html)

Here's an excerpt, you can read the rest in the link provided above:

```
--debug=time
Prints various time profiling information: the time spent executing each 
individual build command; the total build time (time SCons ran from 
beginning to end); the total time spent reading and executing SConscript 
files; the total time spent SCons itself spend running (that is, not 
counting reading and executing SConscript files); and both the total 
time spent executing all build commands and the elapsed wall-clock 
time spent executing those build commands...
```

Comment: Hi Brady. Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it but I'm using parallel building and the output looks really messy so it's difficult to establish the relationships between the targets and the elapsed times.

Comment: I suppose this should be used with a proper output manager that separates different types of output. I haven't found a good recipe for that yet, and no built-in solution apparently exists

Comment: @EvgeniiPuchkaryov the results are displayed on stdout, if you want to do something special with it, perhaps programatically, then yes, something additional would be needed.

Comment: @Brady: Well, I was hoping for some centralized output management for all build components, such that one can choose to direct individual component builds into separate outputs, with standard names and locations. Also separating SCons messages from the stuff printed when a component is compiled or processed otherwise. So id I want to review build times, that messaging is not mixed with the rest.

Comment: @EvgeniiPuchkaryov sounds like an interesting addition, as currently I dont think SCons has anything like that. Try sending an email to scons-users@scons.org